# Elasticsearch DSL: Bucket not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Running the code,

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, A

client = Elasticsearch(timeout=100)

s = Search(using=client, index="cms*")
s.aggs.bucket('ExitCode', 'terms', field='ExitCode').metric('avgCpuEff', 'avg', field='CpuEff')

for hit in s[0:20].execute():
    print hit['ExitCode']
```

yields several ExitCode = 0. I thought a terms bucket is supposed to group all the results that have the same exit code, in this case. What is actually going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over the hits, you need to iterate over the aggregated buckets instead:

```
response = s.execute()
for code in response.aggregations.ExitCode.buckets:
    print(code.key, code.avgCpuEff.value)
```